# Spring Data Neo4j "No property get found for type" exception

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm trying to convert an existing project to use Spring Data and Neo4j, but I'm running into some issues. When I try to build the project, I get the following exception:

```
[etc. ...]
Caused by: 
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property get found for type com.myproject.models.SuperNode
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75)
[... etc.]
```

I can't seem to find any good info on why I would be getting that error, and I'm not sure what exactly is causing it.

Here is most of the SuperNode class:

```
@NodeEntity
public class SuperNode extends AbstractMapValues {

    @GraphId
    private Long superNodeId;

    @NotNull
    private boolean superNodeFullyGenerated = false;

    private BaseLandType likelyLandType;

    private BaseLandType unlikelyLandType;

[methods and such]
}
```

It descends from the AbstractMapValues class:

```
@NodeEntity
public abstract class AbstractMapValues implements Comparable<AbstractMapValues> {

    @GraphId
    public Long id;

    @Range(min = 0, max = MAX_MAP_INT)
    private int xCoor;

    @Range(min = 0, max = MAX_MAP_INT)
    private int yCoor;

    //set only when x and y are set
    @Indexed(indexType = IndexType.POINT)
    private String wkt;

    @Range(min = BASIC_MIN, max = BASIC_MAX)
    private int percipitation;

    @Range(min = -1, max = BASIC_MAX)
    private int topography;

    @Range(min = BASIC_MIN, max = BASIC_MAX)
    private int seaLevel;

 [more int fields, but you get the picture]
 }
```

As you can see these are meant to represent points in a map. I have a Neo4j-spatial dependency in my project which should allow me to use IndexType.POINT.

Then I have the repositories for SuperNode. I have my basic CRUD-type repository interface for it, a custom interface which is implemented by the basic repository, so that I can implement the custom interface and write out the get methods that are going to require making use of the Neo4j-spatial library.

Basic repo:

```
public interface SuperNodeRepo extends CRUDRepository<SuperNode>, SpatialRepository<SuperNode>, SuperNodeRepoCustom {

}
```

Custom interface:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface SuperNodeRepoCustom {

    public SuperNode getSuperNode(int xCoorSuperNode, int yCoorSuperNode) ;

    public List<SuperNode> getSuperNodes(int xmax, int xmin, int ymax, int ymin) ;

}
```

Custom implementation (as you can see it is currently incomplete):

public class SuperNodeRepoCustomImpl implements SuperNodeRepoCustom {

```
public SuperNode getSuperNode(int xCoorSuperNode, int yCoorSuperNode) {
    return null;
}

public List<SuperNode> getSuperNodes(int xmax, int xmin, int ymax, int ymin) {
    return null;
}
```

}

I've tried adding an @Indexed directly to a new field in the SuperNode, but that doesn't help. I've tried it without the spatialRepo being extended.

When I try it without my custom interface being extended I get a different error:

```
No matching bean of type [com.orclands.game.models.SuperNode] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

But I still don't know why am getting that. So in the end, I have two questions. A. what is wrong in my custom interface implementation, and B. what is wrong aside from that!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should only have one @GraphId annotation in your hierarchy.

Comment: Do you have the project on github or somewhere to have a look at it?

Comment: Well, I removed the extra @GraphId, but I am still getting the "No matching bean of type [com.orclands.game.models.SuperNode]" error. I'm afraid I only have it on a private repository, as it's a personal project. I can put up some more info if there might be anything I left out though.

Comment: I do have some other classes in the AbstractMapValues hierarchy annotated as being @NodeEntity, but that don't have any other annotations. That shouldn't make difference in getting an error about the SuperNode though, right?

Comment: I'm really sorry, I didn't post as much info as I should have! I had a stray @Autowired annotation in a service layer method, and it was trying to autowire SuperNode into the method as if it were a setter (as the SuperNode entity was the parameter for the method).

Comment: I'm still not sure why I'm getting the "no property get" error when I add my custom implementation though. Could it have something to do with a bad name for one of my methods, or parameters?

Comment: @CorayThan Have you solved this problem? I'm having this issue too trying to create as repository extension as described in http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/3.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/programming-model.html#d0e2970

Answer (score 0):

```
**@Repository**
public interface SuperNodeRepo extends CRUDRepository<SuperNode>, SpatialRepository<SuperNode>, SuperNodeRepoCustom {

}
```